# Format this datetime without seconds or AM/PM

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have a property that is set to "DateTime?" like this:

```
Public Overridable Property MyDateTime As DateTime?
```

I'm trying to get the hours and minutes without the seconds and without AM or PM.

I tried this:

```
MyDateTime.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString
```

That gives me the hours, minutes, and seconds without AM or PM

And I tried this:

```
MyDateTime.Value.ToShortTimeString
```

This gives me only the hours and minutes, but also gives me AM or PM.

Is there a way to format it so it looks like this?

```
9:10
```

or

```
2:40
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, try `ToString("hh:mm")`. You can change to `HH` if you would like 2pm to be 14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a [custom Date and Time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Try this:

```
MyDateTime.Value.ToString("HH:mm")
```

Comment: this gets rid of the seconds and AM/PM but it puts it in 24 hour time format. Anyway to stick with 12 hour times? thanks

Comment: @999cm999 change the `HH` to `hh`. See the MSDN link for more information on custom formatters. Additionally, use a single H (upper or lower case for 24 hour time) if you don't want a leading zero, like `9` instead of `09`.

Answer (score 3):

The ToString method accepts formatting parameters.

E.g. (12 hour clock)

```
MyDateTime.Value.ToString("h:mm")
```

(24 hour clock)

```
MyDateTime.Value.ToString("H:mm")
```

Comment: Semicolons shouldn't be used for VB.NET.

Comment: TimeOfDay isn't strictly necessary since you are outputting to a string.

Comment: Noted, and changed.  Good eye :)

Comment: @Guvante - Not just unnecessary, but would cause an exception!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
MyDateTime.Value.ToString("h:mm") ' 12 Hour Clock
```

Or:

```
MyDateTime.Value.ToString("H:mm") ' 24 Hour Clock
```

Comment: He is looking for the short form (9:24) not the long form (09:24).

Comment: @Guvante - Good catch.  `h` or `H` for single digits, `hh` or `HH` for leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyDateTime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

This Code show time with AM or PM